# How to provide !important to Color from codebehind

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in which i am trying to provide background color while selection
like

```
this.GrdFormat.Rows[int.Parse(FormatFilterarr[1].ToString())].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e9e9e9");
```

Everything works fine the color get render on the place it supposed to. The only problem which i am facing the color doesn't show.If i try to place `!important` in front of `"#e9e9e9"`
The color get display.

Now the issue is how shall i place !important from codebehind in asp.net

Comment: The better way of doing is that you add a CSS class through code behind and use that CSS class to define !important. instead of Backcolor use CssClass to set class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to directly do it in style attribute, then you can use:

```
this.GrdFormat.Rows[int.Parse(FormatFilterarr[1].ToString())].Styles.Add("background-color", "#e9e9e9 !important");
```